# emoji mart showing hashtag emojis only

Tags: reactjs, emoji, react-typescript

The emoji mart picker is only showing hashtags when I change set to anything but native, im currently using it in react typescript.

```
<div className="picker">
  <AppComponent.EmojiPicker
    set="twitter"
    emojiButtonColors={["#364157"]}
    emojiButtonRadius="8px"
    skinTonePosition="search"         
  />
</div>
```

[Here is the image of whats happening](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/983146620055089194/1030478841929551872/unknown.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import data from "@emoji-mart/data";
import { Picker, PickerProps } from "emoji-mart";

const EmojiPicker = (props: PickerProps | Readonly<PickerProps> | any) => {
    const ref = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

    useEffect(() => {
        new Picker({ ...props, data, ref });
    }, [props]);

    return <div ref={ref} />;
};

export default EmojiPicker;
```

Also I am unsure how to use the emoji component to display a single emoji, it would be much appreciated if you can help me with that too thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to import the Twitter data like this -

```
import data from '@emoji-mart/data/sets/14/twitter.json'
```

Check - https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/issues/611#issuecomment-1148673219